# How to determine the end of list has been reached?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm trying to animate my object according to a set of recorded values from kinect skeleton stream by saving the (x,y,z) stream from the skeletal data into a list and then set my objects x and y position from the x,y of the list. However, once the list end has been reached it starts to animate again from the start. I don't want that - I just want the model position to keep going in the positive X direction. Is there any way I can check if end of the list has been reached and to just update the model position in x direction?

Or is there any other way to continue moving my sprite once the points in the list are over... i dont want it to start animating all the way again..

```
   protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            //position += spriteSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

            //// TODO: Add your update logic here
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f))
            {
                string line;
                Viewport view = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport;
                int maxWidth = view.Width;
                int maxHeight = view.Height;


                while((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {


                    string[] temp = line.Split(',');

                    int x = (int) Math.Floor(((float.Parse(temp[0]) * 0.5f) + 0.5f) * maxWidth);
                    int y = (int) Math.Floor(((float.Parse(temp[1]) * -0.5f) + 0.5f) * maxHeight);


                    motion_2.Add(new Point(x, y));  
                }


            }

                position.X = motion_2[i].X;
                position.Y = motion_2[i].Y;

            i++;

            a_butterfly_up.Update(gameTime);

            a_butterfly_side.Update(gameTime);

            G_vidPlayer.Play(mossV);

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
```

Comment: What is 'f' which you are using as a parameter to your StreamReader? Is there any length parameter for 'f', if not, could you check the length in advance?

Comment: f is just storing a string file path . . for the stream reader to read from . .

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved. . .
I have used int count; instead of i in the above code

```
        if (++count >= motion_2.Count)
        {
            position.X--;

            if (position.X < -200)
            {
                count = 0;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            float x = (float)((motion_2[count].X * 0.5f) + 0.5f) * maxX);
            float y = (float)(((motion_2[count].Y * -0.5f) + 0.5f) * maxY);


            position.X = x;
            position.Y = y;
            scale = (float)motion_2[count].Z;

        }
```